# Jsreport: Correct way to stop jsreport server

Tags: jsreport

I have always stop jsreport server by simple close the commandline. Sometimes it causes new start to fail due to port still in use. What is the correct/safe way to turn off jsreport server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general shutdown functionality in jsreport currently. However I guess you are mainly interested in closing the web server. This can be done in the following way:

```
jsreport.express.server.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear how and where this command should be executed?